# How to create an array of javabeans from multiple selected items on a select list in JSP?

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I have a select list and the user can select multiple options from this list. I would like to create an array of javabeans from this list. How do I do that? The service class has two properties. serviceName, and price. I know how to get the values in a servlet by request.getParameterValues(), but I need to do this with javabeans in my jsp form.

```
<jsp:useBean id="service" scope="session" class="package.class"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="service" property="*"/>

<select size="6" id="serviceSelect" name="Services" multiple="true">
                    <option value="Cleaning" >Cleaning</option>
                    <option value="Washing">Washing</option>
                    <option value="Painting">Painting</option> Security</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a `String[]` property and you have to rename the input field name to start with lowercase so that it conforms the Javabeans spec.

So,

```
private String[] services; // +getter +setter
```

with

```
<select name="services">
```

should do.

Comment: My jsp form action has a servlet. Do I do this in my servlet or should it be done in JSP as a scriptlet?

Comment: Uhm, you asked how to do it with `<jsp:useBean>` and I answered it. Just add that property to the bean and rename the input field name to match the bean property name. That's all. How exactly is my answer unclear? But using a servlet is of course much better, but you've already answered by yourself how to do it: use `getParameterValues()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to put a HTML multi-select selected values in a List of Beans instead of a String array, the cleanest way to go IMHO is to make a custom JSP Tag. You could do something like myTags:advancedSelect tag, that has all the necessary html and javascript code to render your HTML multi select, and then in the Tag support class you could get what was selected in the input and build a list of whatever objects you want from that.